# Multiple view classes in Vaadin

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, vaadin

I'm a newbie in Vaadin, and I've just wondered how can I use multiple View classes? I mean, without nested classes. 
http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/doc/book-examples/branches/vaadin-7/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/advanced/NavigatorUI.java#L21
For example this code without nested classes, like a nice, clean object orientated program code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved after a few hours :)
So if you want to navigate to another view class WITHOUT nested classes, then you have do something like this:

```
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo("main");
```

Of course first of all you have add the View to the navigator container in the init method:

```
MainView main = new MainView();
navigator.addView("main",main);
```

Hope somebody can use this hint wisely :)